# Why use complex envelope to model raw measurements?

Tags: acoustics, measurement, analytic-signal, envelope

The usual answers when asking "why use complex numbers to model measurements?" is usually: (a) Because you are measuring a phenomenon like electricity and magnetism. (b) Because it is super useful for analysis- Fourier, convolutions, differentiation: these are easier on the complex plane.

When discussing seismology, acoustics, and other real-valued measurements, authors still use complex numbers, even if analysis in the time-domain, and no convolutions involved.
The usual argument is that the complex numbers represent the complex envelope of the real valued measurement. But why do that? Is this a sociological/communal habit, or is there a practical advantage in working with the convex envelope of a signal, and not its real version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Imaginary' is a misnomer; they 'exist' as much as reals do. As for the envelope: it provides a meaningful representation of phase and amplitude over time, not otherwise doable with reals alone.

To illustrate, consider a real $x(t) = a(t)\cos(\phi(t))$, where $a(t)$ is amplitude and $\phi(t)$ is phase at time $t$. Suppose we observe $x(t)$, but don't know its function (i.e. righthandside of above). For any $t=t_0$, how do we tell its amplitude or phase? At $t_0$, all we have is $x(t_0)$, which can be at any point in the cycle:

[image]

Enter the [analytic representation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Analytic_signal):

[image]

with amplitude & phase computed as:

$$
a_a(t) = \sqrt{\Re^2 + \Im^2},\ \phi_a(t) = \tan^{-1}(\Im / \Re), \\
\Re = \text{real}(x_a(t)),\ \Im = \text{imag}(x_a(t))
$$

Example with trickier $\phi(t)$:

[image]

**But I seek $x$'s amplitude & phase, not $x_a$'s**: that's the thing, they're the *same*: $x_a(t)$ is constructed precisely so to keep $x(t)$'s $a(t)$ and $\phi(t)$. Not only can we now compute these quantities, but also instantaneous *frequency*, and with some luck, [defy Heisenberg's limitations](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/71398/synchrosqueezing-wavelet-transform-explanation/71399#71399). Particularly once entering the discrete realm however, the method isn't flawless, but works well enough in general.

---

**Why is this appropriate for measured data?** Note that we're not transforming the data in any fundamental way, but rather expressing it in an *equivalent* but more useful form. So we don't say "H2O is liquid", which *assumes* certain temperatures and pressures, but more like "H2O has two hydrogen and one oxygen atoms", i.e. exact same thing but reformulated.

Whether the results are *meaningful*, however, does use assumptions: we assume the data is mainly composed of (1) periodic (repeating over time), and (2) sinusoidal processes. For acoustics, both hold very well; air compresses and expands periodically and sinusoidally over a local time segment. Then it's meaningful to ask: what's $a(t)$ and $\phi(t)$ of this physical sinusoidal process?

Assumption (3) is equally crucial: the data has a *single intrinsic mode* or 'major frequency component'. For example, if we have two A.M. sines, $f=2\text{Hz}, 4\text{Hz}$ out of phase, then we need *two* amplitudes and phases, $a_1(t), a_2(t)$ and $\phi_1(t), \phi_2(t)$, so a simple analytic transform won't suffice. For this we use methods like STFT, CWT, and synchrosqueezing to decompose the signal into its components.

Lastly, assumption (2) is flexible: if signal is, say, triangular waves instead of sinusoidal, then we simply re-interpret resulting $a(t)$ and $\phi(t)$.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. From which I learn that the complex envelope decomposes a signal into the instantaneous phase and amplitude. But this is an analysis/processing method. I still wonder why to assume this is the measurement model? Say in acoustics? Or seismology?

Comment: @JohnRos Added a section; let me know if something's unclear, I may have misunderstood the question.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent answer and clarification!