# Can Synchrosqueezing be use to Derive IIR Filter From Impulse Response

Tags: filters, filter-design, finite-impulse-response, infinite-impulse-response, poles-zeros

I am looking for alternate solutions to determine the IIR filter coefficients from the impulse response, or more specifically determine the closest IIR filter for a given FIR filter. Much of this is covered at [this related post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/27085/convert-a-fir-to-an-equivalent-iir), but synchrosqueezing was not mentioned, and as suggested and referenced by OverLordGoldDragon at [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/73362/50076), this may be a useful application of synchrosqueezing.  Has that already been explored for use in FIR to IIR transformation specifically and would it have practical advantages over the other known approaches (as summarized in the referenced post)?

Comment: Dan, have you seen [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/27085/4298)?

Comment: @MattL. No, I should have searched more carefully! My question can actually be more specific if synchrosqueezing could be used effectively for this, given OverLordGoldDragon's comment about finding the decaying exponentials effectively in the presence of noise.  Let me change the title and intro

Comment: I deleted all my other thoughts with possibly recognizing patterns of poles to their equivalent series (zeros).... that's on my list to dig in further on my own and if it has merit I can post it as an answer to that other post. Simplifying this one to the synchrosqueezing question, of doing that on an impulse response.

Comment: [Let's talk.](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1778/50076)