# Compared with the real-valued continuous wavelet, what are the advantages of the complex-valued continuous wavelets?

Tags: wavelet, complex

I noticed that there are two types of wavelet functions, i.e. the real-valued, such as the Mexican hat wavelet, and the complex-valued, such as the Morlet wavelet.  How was the complex-valued wavelet function proposed? What are their advantages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complex, or analytic wavelets enable:

1. Instantaneous frequency, amplitude, and phase extraction - [detailed post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/71399/50076).
2. Robust feature extraction for classification, stable against time-warping deformations (and, if coupled with time averaging, robust to time shifts), and averaged information recovery via higher-order transforms -- [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.6763.pdf), [lecture](https://youtu.be/4eyUReyIPXg)
3. Exact analyticity enables [superior time localization](https://sci-hub.st/10.1109/TSP.2008.2007607) - example on [hyperbolic chirp](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16495490/107903903-d9b69880-6f63-11eb-9478-8ead016cf6f8.png)

Although lacking negative frequencies by definition, they aren't limited to real inputs: complex inputs are handled with the anti-analytic complement that lacks *positive* frequencies.

In contrast, real wavelets are advantageous for detecting fast transients and analyzing fractals (e.g. perturbation, noise analysis) - ch6 of [Wavelet Tour](https://wavelet-tour.github.io/), and [ch4](https://www.di.ens.fr/%7Emallat/papiers/WaveletTourChap1-2-3.pdf) for analytic.

Comment: Can the real-valued wavelet reconstruct the signal by a single integral?

Comment: @WangYun Unsure, seems possible on real-valued inputs; I could take a look in another post.