# What exactly is meant by "translation invariant dictionaries/wavelets"?

Tags: wavelet, terminology, cwt, discrete-wavelet-transform

I'm trying to wrap my head around the notion of translation invariance in terms of dictionaries/wavelets. For example in [Lecture Notes, Page 41](https://matthewhirn.files.wordpress.com/2018/02/math-994-003_lecture-031.pdf) its written that one starts with a family of atoms/wavelets $(\psi_j)_{j\in \mathbb{Z}}$ and adds all translates $t\in 
\mathbb{R}$ via defining
\begin{equation*}
\psi_{j,t}(x) := \psi_j (x - t).
\end{equation*}
Now the calculation of the coefficients for a singal $f$ becomes
\begin{equation}\label{calc coeff}
\Phi f (j,t) = \left\langle f, \psi_{j,t}\right\rangle = \int_\mathbb{R} f(x) \psi_j^\ast (t - x) \mathrm{d}x = f \ast \psi_j^\ast (t),
\end{equation}
where $\psi_j^\ast(x) := \psi_j(-x)$. To me, translation invariance means something like $f(x) = f(x-t)$, but I don't understand/see where this equations holds for the above "argumentation"?

Furthermore, reading some [Wikipedia on Stationary Wavelet Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_wavelet_transform), it says in the first sentence "to overcome the lack of translation-invariance of the discrete wavelet transform", i.e. when the translation $t\in \mathbb{R}$ becomes $t\in \mathbb{Z}$. Why is the discrete wavelet transform not translation invariant? The calculation for the coefficients $\left\langle f, \psi_{j,t} \right\rangle$ is the same, but only discrete convolution instead of continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rather translation *equivariant*:

$$
\text{CWT}_{s, t}x(t - t_0) = \text{CWT}_{s, t - t_0}x(t) \tag{1}
$$

and

$$
\langle x(t−t_0),\psi(t) \rangle= \langle x(t), \psi(t+t_0)\rangle \tag{2}
$$

That is, when a signal is shifted, its representation is also shifted but not modified (like LTI). This makes its derived *features*, such as energy and norm, or most manipulations of coefficients, *invariant* - hence the terminology (though agreeably misleading).

#### DWT

The DWT is likewise equivariant *at source* - i.e. *before subsampling*. Suppose subsampling by x2:

$$
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0] \rightarrow [0, 2, 4, 6, 0]
$$
now (circular-)shift by 1:
$$
[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0] \rightarrow [0, 1, 3, 5, 0]
$$

If it were equivariant, we'd get $[0, 0, 2, 4, 6]$ - but now, our manipulations (e.g. $\sum |\text{coef}|^2$) will no longer yield the same results. Nonetheless, "at source" equivariance is much more than no equivariance at all, and some manipulations can take advantage of it.

#### Equivariant dictionaries

One can notice that $(2)$ is an *identity* - i.e. it's always true. The idea is that "shift" for wavelets is defined this way to begin with, i.e. "shift by $t_0$" means $\psi(t - t_0)$, which isn't the case for all functions (e.g. its Fourier transform, shifted as a function of frequency, also changes its width, breaking equivariance). To define a shift this way means to make it a convolutional operator, and the derived representation LTI.

#### Invariance

There is an important sense in which [complex wavelets](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/76093/50076) are invariant:

$$
\text{CWT}(x(t)) = \text{CWT}(x(t - t_0))
$$

While the equality never strictly holds with wavelets alone (except at infinite scale), the distance between shifted coefficients can be made as low as the application demands with further steps; with wavelets alone, the greater the scale, the lesser the distance. Time-shift invariance is a bedrock of the [scattering transform](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.6763.pdf).

See [related post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/76639/50076).

---

> but only discrete convolution instead of continuous

The distinction is unimportant: they're both implemented as discrete convolutions. The difference is in subsampling scheme and choice of wavelets.

Comment: Thanks that clarified already a lot! I would have a follow-up question: For the last point on distinction between discrete/continuous, could you give examples of wavelets which can be used both, for CWT and DWT and/or which can be used for one but not the other? (I'm mostly familiar the analytical definition of Shannon-, Haar- or Meyer-Wavelet)

Comment: @stish Any DWT wavelet can be used for CWT, but not other way around; most CWT wavelets are ill-suited (or invalid) for DWT. E.g. Morlet, Morse, Mexican Hat, Bump - anything that cannot effectively tile the frequency domain _without overlaps_.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Just a clarification, this means that if I have two overlapping scalograms (by CWT) produced by two overlapping windows, the overlapped parts would show the same?

Comment: @EddyPiedad Unsure what you mean. Two separate scalograms cannot be easily overlapped as they're multi-resolution, also likely computed with different paddings. If we the signal is split in two, then the in-between region, outside the influence of boundary effects, will be identical yes.

Comment: If this is about whether we can do overlap-add/overlap-save for CWT, it's a yes.

Comment: I think the latter is what I mean but can you demonstrate it? Assume a time series signal and a window, $win$, of size $N$. Two identical windows overlap with overlap length size of $N-N/2$. There are two CWTs from these two windows. Will the overlap area of these two CWTs be the same?