# Time-frequency analysis of a nonlinear system

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency-response, time-frequency, sensor, non-linear

I have empirically developed a sensor failure detection system which works fine. The system receives inputs from different types of sensors. Because of noise characteristics, I use low pass filters on some sensors output. In the system, all these sensor readings form a signal which is constantly compared with a model and in the end create a remainder signal. In case of a sensor failure, the remainder signal violates pre-defined thresholds and raise an alarm.

For the system analysis, I use superposition law, meaning that except one, all inputs are considered zero and a step signal is propagated through the system. Here the step signal represents a sensor failure. With various approximations, I am able to get the corresponding transfer functions. That way, I can justify the system performance. However, this has raised lots of ambiguities. I am asked to justify and optimize the system performance (with the simultaneous consideration of all inputs) through time or frequency analysis. The result can be a frequency response or a mathematical equation or other system performance representations.

My questions: Since I am dealing with a relatively complex, nonlinear system, is there any way to analyze and optimize its performance with the simultaneous consideration of all inputs/sensor readings? Is there some good literature that I can study this topic from?

Comment: The general way to represent a nonlinear system that is also *"dynamic"*, in that it also has memory of the past, is wirh Volterra series.  But it's a big mess.

Answer (score 1):

If superposition works, then independent mode/component extraction is of interest. [Synchrosqueezing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/71399/50076) is well-suited for this task. Extracted features can ten be fed to an anomaly detection system - optionally with [Gaussianization](https://github.com/gregversteeg/gaussianize).

Other methods can be applied to the extracted components as if they were individual signals, so the described approach is expansive and flexible.