# Computable Time-Frequency Distribution without Cross-Terms

Tags: signal-analysis, power-spectral-density, spectrogram, time-frequency, spectrum-estimation

**Context:**

I have a single receiver that is receiving multiple signals. Each signal has a few strong harmonics, but I don't know the fundamental frequency. I would like to display them on a spectrogram like display, but when the number of signals increases beyond three or four, the spectrogram gets very cluttered.

In other words:

$$ | X_{1}(f) + X_{2}(f) + \cdots + X_{N}(f)   |^2  = |X_{1}|^2(f) + |X_{2}|^2(f) + \cdots + |X_{N}|^2(f) + \text{cross-terms} $$

**Question:**

Is there another time-frequency distribution that eliminates or greatly reduces these cross-terms,  and is also computable on a digital computer in a reasonable time [ideally less than O(N^2)]?

**Comments:**

I know other distributions exist, e.g. the Wigner-Ville distribution, but generally, they seem to try and improve the resolution of the spectrogram at the expense of greater cross-terms. I would be happy with the opposite -- less cross-terms but also less resolution.

Answer (score 2):

[Synchrosqueezing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/71398/synchrosqueezing-wavelet-transform-explanation/71399#71399). Diminishes Wigner-Ville interaction disadvantages as described [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.2437).

Comment: I have never heard of this -- I need to figure out how to apply it to my situation, but, it seems promising.

Answer (score 1):

All time-frequency representations that can be formulated as part of Cohen's class ([bilinear ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_time%E2%80%93frequency_distribution)) will have cross-terms.  There are post-processing / filtering approaches (as mentioned on the Wikipedia page) that allow them to be filtered out.

OverLordGoldDragon's approach seems more sensible than anything in Cohen's class --- including the Wigner-Ville, STFT, or the other more esoteric representations.

Comment: Ah okay, I have heard of Cohen's class before, but I didn't realize ALL T-F representations could be formulated as part of his class.

Comment: @TheDude Not *all*, but certainly most of the ones you've heard about.