# Emperical mode decomposition problem

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, power-spectral-density, empirical-mode-decomposition

I am using Empirical Mode Decomposition (EMD) algorithm to decompose a vibration signal generated by outer race bearing defect using case western réserve University data.

I am facing a problem: unlike noise-free faulty signal results, noisy signal results (I add noise to this signal with `snr=3` or `snr=-3`) in only the first Intrinsic Mode Function (IMF) selected and giving the fault information.

Is it possible that only the first IMF be sensitive to the fault?

Comment: A more robust but inspired alternative is [synchrosqueezing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/71399/50076).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As its name suggests, Empirical Mode Decomposition is empirical. Therefore, its behavior is very unstable and hard to predict. Moreover, it is highly computationally demanding.
For bearing faults' detection, I strongly suggest cyclostationary analysis. This is the state of the art and it is covered [throughly](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0888327010002530). For this task, EMD was popular for a short time but I strongly suggest avoiding it.

Comment: I'm really grateful for your response, I'll take your suggestion into consideration